# Is it possible to have a block cursor in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-cursor

Not sure it is most appropriate to post it here. I don't find it on either Sublime's official/unofficial documents or the web.

Anyone has a solution to have a vim/terminal type block cursor in sublime text?

Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I added:  ["inverse_caret_state": true,] to the preference file and it looks like an underline type cursor now, but still wondering if anyone has a solution for a block cursor that are typically used in vim/terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out by looking at some settings in afterglow - twilight, these lines in the color themes would work well with caret_inverse_style: true

```
<dict>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>background</key>
        <string>#2E2E2E</string>
        <key>caret</key>
        <string>#4169E1</string>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#d6d6d6</string>
        <key>invisibles</key>
        <string>#FFFFFF40</string>
        <key>lineHighlight</key>
        <string>#FFFFFF08</string>
        <key>selection</key>
        <string>#4169E1</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

specifically, the "caret color" will be the color of the caret, and the "selection" color will be the background of the area of the caret (similar to a block cursor.

Answer (score 19):

You can try out the package that @user2365566 mentioned. I personally didn't like the way that cursor looked.

Here is an alternative, just add following into your `Preferences.sublime-settings`:

```
{
    "caret_extra_width": 5,
    "caret_style": "solid",
    "wide_caret": true
}
```

You can change the `caret_extra_width` number to whatever you like, based on how wide you want the cursor to be.

Comment: thank you! It looks like the bigger/wider cursor will override the characters under it though, do you have a workaround for that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by overriding the characters?

Comment: Hello, I mean when the cursor is wide, it covers the letter, because I guess the cursor is on top of the letter? Not sure how we can change the cursor to the background, so the letter is not covered by the cursor? @saadq

Comment: Are you using Vintage mode? I assumed you were because of your post. If you have vintage mode on, the cursor should be transparent when in  on the letter normal or visual mode like this: http://imgur.com/vhblM3J

Comment: Thanks! It works in vintage mode, but I am curious whether it is possible to configure it under the normal editing mode in sublime. thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure if there is a way to get this result without vintage mode, sorry.

Comment: This looks horrible.  In vim, the block cursor reverses the color of the letter under it.  So if you have black background and white text, when the cursor is over a letter, the letter becomes black, the cursor is white.  However, the above does not achieve the same effect in sublime: the cursor is white and it's over white text on a blackground.

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, the plugin mentioned below would be preferable. I personally am not a fan of a contrast like that and prefer to keep things subtle like here: http://i.imgur.com/f4fPtNn.png

Answer (score 11):

This is now possible as of Build 3190 (from 19 February 2019). You can enable this with

```
"block_caret": true
```

in your user settings. Your theme may not have a style for this, so if the default color of the caret isn't to your liking, it can be changed in your theme by adding

```
<key>blockCaret</key>
<string>#FFCC00</string>
```

into your theme's `settings` section. It will look something like this:

[image: block_caret example image]

Answer (score 8):

As far as i know there is no way to do this in ST3 right out of the box at the moment.

There are however packages such as https://github.com/karlhorky/BlockCursorEverywhere that should solve your problem.

Comment: thank you, do you know if blockcursoreverywhere plugin only works with vim mode? I couldn't get it to work with normal sublime editing mode.

Comment: @laomao, I'm not sure if it's intentional, but I found it works as you described: only in vim mode. For me, that's desirable.

Comment: @kevin the package should display a Block Cursor without Vintage or Vintageous as well https://github.com/karlhorky/BlockCursorEverywhere/issues/10#issuecomment-163170479

Answer (score 3):

It's simply based on your preference. This method is called Caret in Sublime Text. Go to **Preferences > Settings – User** and add following lines-

```
"caret_style": "phase",

"caret_extra_bottom": 0,
"caret_extra_top": 30,
"caret_extra_width": 2,

"line_padding_bottom": 5,
"line_padding_top": 10,
```

All the values are based on your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit `caret_extra_width` to be about 10, or the size of your font.